# Wordpress footer menu floating with height of footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress theme and I'm stuck on my footer menu.

I want to display the menu like this picture.

[image: Footer menu design]

The menu items contain sub menu items so the html is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Menu item 1
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>
            sub menu item 1
            </li>

            <li>
            sub menu item etc
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        Menu item 2
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>
            sub menu item 1
            </li>

            <li>
            sub menu item etc
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Like this it puts it vertical on top of each other of course, floating the li puts all the main menu items next to each other.

But what I have to make according to the design is that the main menu item gets to the next column when the div height runs out.

It has to be dynamic otherwise I would have used CSS selectors.

Something with javascript/jquery maybe?

Thanks.

I didn't think it would be relevant but here is the CSS I currently use which just floats the items left

```
.sub-menu .menu-item {
    margin-top: 0!important;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 0; 
}
#lastfooter ul {
    padding-top: 8px;
}

#lastfooter ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#lastfooter ul li a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#lastfooter ul li a:hover{
    color: #e74d25;
}
```

Comment: What have you done already? Show your `CSS`.

Comment: I'll add the CSS but it's not relavent to this because the CSS now just floats the items left

Comment: It is relevant. Just show it in a fiddle so that we can make something of it and help you out. Geloof me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not clearly define how you want the menu to work ...

> 1 2 3
>   4 5 6
>
> **or**
>
> 1 3 5
>   2 4 6

Maybe the [CSS multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) is what you are looking for (*for moderns browsers only*)

```
.columns{
    column-count:4;
    column-gap:2em;
}
```

More complete demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Y88YZ/

Comment: Thanks for responding, I really like this answer and I'm going to use this. Now I only have to find a solution for older browsers since the company I work for still suports IE8. PS. You rock!

Comment: @andredewaard check the columns polyfill at https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn

Comment: I can't get that to work in IE but i made it work in all supported browsers. In IE8 i used display: none.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage these with CSS. Try the below code:

```
.fl { float:left;}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
#footer .footer  {
    border:dashed 2px #ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
}
#footer .footer ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:170px;
    margin:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
#footer .footer ul .listing_head {
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
}
#footer .footer ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    line-height:22px;
    font-size:12px;
}
#footer .footer ul li a {
    color:#0152ab;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#footer .footer ul .feedback {
    font-size:19px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#375078;
}
#footer .footer ul .feedback_form label {
    font-size:13px; 
    color:#000;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
#footer .footer ul .feedback_form label span {
    color:#900;
}
#footer .footer ul .feedback_form input[type="text"], #footer .footer ul .feedback_form textarea {
    width:180px;
    border: 1px #b7b4b4 solid;
    min-height:22px;
    padding:2px;
    color:#5a5858;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
#footer .footer ul .feedback_form input[type="submit"]{
    height:29px;
    color:#900;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    float:right;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/sushilkandola/82HHJ/**

Comment: This doesn't work with what I want because this makes it a static menu and with the wordpress it has to be dynamic because the customer has to be able to add a menu item.

Comment: What is your interpretation of a dynamic menu? I mean, it is actually what you want, but you have to style it further.

Comment: @andredewaard You have to apply CSS in same way. As you are adding menus from word-press then you have to create the logic in PHP, like parent and child links/

Comment: It's not actually what I want because his code has divs with a float left. The menu from wordpress is just a series of ul and li like I showed in the question.